# Symfony2: Entity recreated after renamed

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I've created a bundle Super, and created relative Entity "sin_table1.php" as "sin_table1" mysql table generation.

After an:

```
 php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeSuperBundle
```

and

```
  php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Now i can see the full mysql table generated.

But if i rename sin_table1.php to another name as "mysql_schema.php", and i try to reload that commands, doctrine/symfony2 recreate "sin_table1.php" Entity file.

I tried to grep "sin_table1" key into symfony2 root project, but nothing found. Only caches, logs and the two Entitiy files(sin_table1.php & mysql_schema.php).

I've tried to clean cache, but nothing happened, always sin_table1.php recreated, and conflicts with mysql_schema.php because there is a double decaration of the same class.

How i can resolve it? where doctrine have sin_table1 entity configuration saved? why this happen?

i think that i've lost something reading manual....

Comment: Can you put more code please ? Your entity use annotation ? Maybe you have a @Table(name="sin_table1").

Comment: These are my first experiments with symfony and doctrine, and i think after another test that the filename must be the same of the contained class. This is a my hypothesis/supposition, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Namefile: mysql_schema.php

```
namespace Acme\SuperBundle\Entity;`
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`
    /**`
     * @ORM\Entity`
     * @ORM\Table(name="sin_table1")`
     */`
    class sin_table1`
    {....`
```

In my new test, i've renamed clas as "sin_tablerrrrrrrrrr" and also @ORM\Table(name="sin_tablerrrrrrrrrr"....

and the result will be another file sin_tablerrrrrrrrrr.php created

If my supposition that namefile must be the same of the class, i could be sign as solved.

Answer (score 0):

- I've always set my class name identical to my php file name. I guess it's more a developer convention / best practice that an obligation.
- Anyway, I've got the same problem few weeks ago and I saw that the command `php app/console doctrine:schema:drop` doesn't delete a renamed table. The table with the old name was not deleted by the command. So when I updated I had the both tables. Maybe it was your problem.

Comment: yep, i've understood the development convention... 
This situation happened to me because i need to create two pair of classes, one for querying mysql and another for querying elasticsearch database.
This because daily logs will be entried and deleted in mysql table(as a daily cache), and before mysql dataclean, data must be copied in a elasticsearch database.
So i need to make 2 classes working in a parallel system for extract same data.
Namefile was only for understand a mysql data connection entity.
Nothing to do,i'm obligated, i've to get used ^_^

Comment: I'm not sur to understand but if you want to create two table to manage logs I suggest you to set an event scheduler in MySQL to save the data and then delete the old data. Also, you can running a command by using a cron task. It's strange to have two tables for this but maybe you don't have the choice. I wish you every success for the future.

Comment: sure i know well cron task and mysql.
But i dont need 2 tables in mysql, but one in mysql and the second in elasticsearch database.
I use elastic search because mysql is very good for little data, but queryes in a giant db are too slow. Elasticsearch database is very different, it can give results vevy very fast in a giant database.
As you know logs are very massive data, and mysql can't support or to be fast.
So i use only mysql for daily logs, after data will be paste in elastic search by cron as you understand.

Look this: http://www.elasticsearch.org/